# How many divisions does the GPU's texture mapper do in parallel?

Tags: rendering, gpu

Perspective-correct texture mapping requires one division per pixel. Before the advent of GPUs this was a problem because this was quite heavy to do on the CPU (especially back in the days of non-SSE single-core CPUs, when they were capable of calculating only one division at a time, requiring several dozens of clock cycles per division).

After GPUs became a thing, however, this solved the problem and games got perfectly perspective-correct texture mapping on each rendered pixel in real-time.

But this raises the question: How fast are the divisions done by the GPU when it's texture-mapping, and how many divisions is it doing in parallel? How is this done? Is there like a huge array of units in the GPU doing hundreds of divisions in parallel, like a huge SIMD unit dedicated to divisions? Or how is it done?

Comment: This sounds like a question about the internals of computing hardware, not about how to develop games that run on that hardware. Since game developers are usually not also GPU chip engineers, you may be posing this question to the wrong audience.

Comment: Which stackexchange site would, thus, be correct for this kind of question?

Comment: The general consensus appears to be that Super User is the right stackexchange site for hardware questions. It's a very large community so you will likely get some great answers. https://superuser.com/

Comment: [The Computer Graphics StackExchange currently hosts several questions about how GPU chips carry out operations](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgpu%5D+division).

Comment: The computer graphics stackexchange site seems to have a really low amount of traffic (as in almost nobody is viewing my posts there). I asked this and another similar question there, and got no responses, and less than 10 views on each so far. It might be the "right place" to ask such questions in terms of content, but not in terms of actually getting an answer. Is there any better place if you want to get actual answers?